# Orange widget development: How to iterate through gui widget label to display output of calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, orange

I am trying to create a simple widget using Orange. It calculates the mean of a given data input but I am unsure of how to iterate through the gui widget label to show each instance inside the widget box when it is uploaded to Orange.

```
import Orange
import Orange.data
from Orange.widgets.widget import OWWidget, Input, Output
from Orange.widgets import gui

class OWtest(OWWidget):
name = "Mean Data"
description = "Mean of data attributes"
#icon = ".svg"
priority = 20

class Inputs:
    data = Input("Data", Orange.data.Table)

class Outputs:
    infoData = Output("Info Data", Orange.data.Table)

want_main_area = False

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    box = gui.widgetBox(self.controlArea, "Info")
    self.line_a = gui.widgetLabel(box, 'No data present')

@Inputs.data
def set_data(self, dataset):
    if dataset is not None:
        for d in dataset:
            print(d)        
        average = lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)
        for x in dataset.domain.attributes:
            self.line_a.setText("%s %.2f" % (x.name, average([d[x] for d in dataset]))) 
            print("%s %.2f" % (x.name, average([d[x] for d in dataset])))
```

At the moment it is only showing one line within the widget box, where i have only defined self.line_a.

How would I loop through to create and display multiple widget labels to fit with the output produced by the average calculation? I am unsure on where the loop would fit or is there a simple step that i am missing? I have been looking through documentation and trying to fix the problem but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First constructing the full string and only then setting it as the `line_a` text should do the trick:

```
        text = '\n'.join("%s %.2f" % (x.name, average([d[x] for d in dataset]))
                         for x in dataset.domain.attributes)
        self.line_a.setText(text)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect! I realise my mistake